# JAWS reads removal of DOM node within an `aria-live` region only in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, accessibility, internet-explorer-11, wai-aria, jaws-screen-reader

The live region is:

```
<div aria-live='assertive' id='abc'> </div>
```

In JavaScript, the first change I make is to

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="<span>Processing</span>";
```

Next, I make another change:

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML="<span>Done</span>";
```

JAWS has no problem in Firefox and reads both "Processing" and "Done". But IE reads "Processing Removing Processing Done"

I understand that I am replacing a `<span>` with a new `<span>`. But how do I make JAWS ignore giving that update of removal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way I have successfully defeated this bug in IE is to hide the element being deleted, add the new element, then later, remove the hidden element.

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful. I see that just hiding the previous span is enough. I do not need to remove it, since I replace the entire innerHTML with my new contents (Done)

Comment: None of the two file you provided use this technique. First one does not hide anything. The second use different region for another matter as stated in the source code: *"This is to circumvent bugs in browsers that will stop announcing updates to the same div if these are too repetitive."*

Comment: you are correct, the examples do not implement this technique, but as confirmed by @KannarKK, the technique does fix the problem

Comment: Yes because you no longer use innerHTML method (which IE interprets as a text modification).

Answer (score -1):

To understand this bug in IE, you have to look to the documentation for the `aria-relevant` attribute which specify which changes you want the screenreader to be notified.

See the following page in the Microsoft documentation: [aria-relevant attribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd433066(v=vs.85).aspx)

In your case, IE considers (falsely) that you are doing a text update (because of the use of `innerHTML` which is considered as a string), so it notifies deletion and addition:

> Updates are announced only as nodes are added, **or as text is added or removed**.

The solution should be to add or remove with the use of `addChild()` and `removeChild()` functions.

Comment: aria-relevant is set to additions by default. This is a bug in IE

Comment: Here is where the default value (additions text) is specified http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-relevant

Comment: I don't see the point. If `aria-relevant` were set by default to `additions`, obviously deletions won't be announced. Pointing to a document specifying "additions text" which is what the MSDN doc already specifies does not give any extra information. Here the bug is that Internet Explorer considers call to innerHTML as a text modification. Using addChild() and removeChild() or append() in jQuery will give you the expected result.

Comment: Are you kidding me ;-)? Both of the link you provided use jQuery and no one has any problem with it. See my comment under your answer.

Comment: did you test that using jQuery.append() fixes the problem as you claim in your comment?

Comment: Yes and you successfully did so apparently. But, as I said in my answer, this is not a jQuery related question, nor a jQuery related bug, it's a bug in Internet Explorer accessibility API when using `innerHTML` containing tag names. Maybe we use different versions of OS/Jaws/IE, which I can't guarantee? You should provide more information of your configuration if it failed with `addChild()` and `removeChild()`.